# Angular & uirouter - how to define routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I am creating an application that uses Angular 6 (`6.0.6`) and @uirouter/angular (`2.0.0`). But my app does not reconize the route '`/login`', it does only navigate to '`/`' (even if I remove the '`otherwise: '/'`')

This application exists of multiple modules with multiple pages. The structure can be described as follows:

```
app/
-- home/
---- home.module.ts
---- home.component.ts
---- home.route.ts
---- home.scss
---- home.html
-- login/
---- login.module.ts
---- login.component.ts
---- login.route.ts
---- login.scss
---- login.html
-- app.module.ts
-- app.component.ts
```

Both modules have a separate routing file. The way I thought it would work was as follows (simplified example, don't mind the missing parts):

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    UIRouterModule.forRoot({otherwise: '/'}),
    HomeModule,
    LoginModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

---

**home.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    UIRouterModule.forChild({states: [homeState]}),
    NavbarModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class HomeModule {
}
```

**home.route.ts**

```
export const homeState: Ng2StateDeclaration = {
  name: 'home',
  url: '/',
  component: HomeComponent
};
```

---

**login.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    UIRouterModule.forChild({states: [loginState]}),
  ],
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class LoginModule {
}
```

**login.route.ts**

```
export const loginState: Ng2StateDeclaration = {
  name: 'login',
  url: '/login',
  component: LoginComponent
};
```

---

I expected that the `UIRouterModule.forChild()` method would just add the route to the configuration. But the `/login` route is not reconized and it just navigates back to `/`. I do **not** want to create a submodule where all my routing happens, because then I will also have to import all the dependencies my components have in that module (so far separation of concern and modularization).

This would look as follows for my example app:

```
const states = [homeState, loginState];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    UIRouterModule.forChild({states: [states], otherwise: '/'}),
    NavbarModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomeComponent, loginComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

The `loginComponent` does not need the `NavBarModule`, but still gets it this way..

Since this doesn't work I am clearly doing something wrong. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I should fix it?

Comment: Why are you not using the Angular Router Module? Do you want to preserve the State?

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture may need a bit more thought. Have a look at the approach in [this blog post](https://www.technouz.com/4644/angular-5-app-structure-multiple-modules/) which uses the native Angular router to achieve what you are trying to do.